# Remove noise, sky glow and vignetting in GIMP

Tags: blur, noise, gimp, astronomy, vignette

I have an photo of a comet. I'm trying to use GIMP to improve it but it's like space shuttle to me.

Can you please describe steps to

1. get rid of or reduce vignetting in the corners of the image
2. get rid of or reduce sky glow and make the sky darker while keeping stars and comet at approximately the same brightness (improve contrast?)
3. reduce digital noise (perhaps some form of Gaussian blur that would not affect the sharpness of the stars and comet?)

Thanks!

[Comet 46P/Wirtanen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVNP1.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

AS a first step, use the Curves tool and drag the origin to the left:

[image]